# be suitable to V

Tags: infinitives, infinitive-phrases

Is "suitable to V" used naturally in the following? Sentence (a) is from CNN. If (a) is okay but (b) is not, why the difference?

> a. Ever since, Curiosity has been investigating the geologic record to understand when Mars might have been most **suitable to host** life.

> b. John is most **suitable to perform** the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Suitable' means *capable of suiting*. You might speak about someone or something being 'suitable' in a prospective way - for example, a 'suitable candidate' for a job has not yet been put in the job.

Example (b) doesn't seem incorrect, but if something has already proven to suit the task or situation it may be better to say '*suited*'.

> John is best suited to the task.